# How to copy RAID 1 HDDs from one server to another Identical server

Tags: windows, raid, software-raid, hardware-raid, raid1

I have one IBM X3100M4, type 2582 windows server and having 2 x 500 GB HDDs in RAID Copy. Now brought new server and having blank HDDs. How can I copy RAID HDDs from Old server to new server?

I have tried EaseUS but it couldn't resolve the problem as it seems works only on Desktops.

Comment: The risky procedure is to extract one of the disks and place it in the new server, hoping that you can use it to seed a new mirror. Other procedures include usually booting from a CD and using a software (acronis, ghost, linux if you're dd expert, ...)

Answer (score 0):

There's far too many unanswered questions here to be able to give a good answer.  What's the OS? Why do you wish to transfer the disks?  What's the desired outcome?

In general terms though, what you need to do is perform a full backup of your existing server and restore it to your new server.